# How do I make my site background change every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a simple page, with a background using the tag 
`body { background-image: url("bgimage.jpg"); }`

How do I make that image switch to a different image every (x) seconds?

I want the background to be kind of a slide show in a way..

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com). I've used this plugin a lot of time and it's very good.

It also has a lot of options and a good  API reference.

Otherwise, if you want to write it yourself, check other answers.